# Extend Skype For Business Call Window

Tags: skype-for-business, skypedeveloper

I would like to extend the Skype For Business Call Window with a new Button with some functionality. Is this possible with SFB? How? Any guideline would be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft don't provide any official to extend the SFB client call UI.  The best you can do is to create your own window that floats near the call window providing your extended functionality. I've seen some companies do this.

Your only other option is to run in UI Suppression Mode and provide all the UI yourself.

Comment: Thanks. I need to open a custom window that lists all my contacts in Skype, then upon clicking on a contact, I want to transfer the call to the selected contact. Do you think this works?

Answer (score 2):

We have a good managed API for extending the Lync 2013 client and it also works with the Skype for Business client. If you want to access your contacts and show them in another process, read https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj933232.aspx.